# Find count greater than 1 in Azure CosmosDB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am querying the below to get the count, uniqueid, Amount
Select uniqueID,c.AmtPercent, count(1) as count from c Group by c.uniqueId, c.AmtPercent

I want the rows where count(1) > 1
Please see the attached
[image]

Comment: Could you please add some more information to your question? What is your input and expected output.

Comment: Please check the added info above. I am querying a collection in Azure Cosmosdb.  I have tried with subquery and its not supported in cosmosdb

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) - be sure to edit your question to properly format your sample data , query, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: Could you please share what is your expected output and any errors you are facing with?